# How to generate random strings from Context-Free Grammar in GNF

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, randomized-algorithms

I need to generate random strings given a grammar in Greibach Normal Form.

The naive approach would be to generate a random integer `n` and perform `n` traversals of production rules, as every traversal adds exactly one symbol to the string. The problem with this approach is that the choice of productions to expand cannot be entirely random, as some planning is required to ensure that at length `n` it is possible to terminate at an empty string.

Comment: Do you have any particular distribution in mind?

Comment: Why pick $n$? Why not just expand rules randomly? At the moment, your question isn't precise enough to answer, because you've not said what distribution you want. Note that "at random" does not mean "equiprobably".

Comment: I agree with the other comments.  Foreshadowing: if you have a particular distribution in mind, a useful building block is to be able to *count* the number of strings of a given length; and that can be done with dynamic programming (e.g., CYK parsing).

Comment: Does "Greibach Normal Form" have anything to do with "random"? Suppose the algorithm changes the grammar from GNF to CNF, does it matter?